# WARNING: "next_online_pgdat" [/**/test.ko] undefined

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, linux-device-driver

I am writing a kernel module where I am using the function for_each_online_pgdat()... to iterate over all the nodes of memory and then all the zones to retrieve some data for all the zones. It is giving the warning while compiling the kernel module.
I am also getting the similar error for for_each_zone()...

```
root@ubuntu:/home/**/# make make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/**/'
CC [M] /home/**/test.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "next_online_pgdat" [/home/**/test.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "first_online_pgdat" [/home/**/test.ko] undefined!
CC /home/**/test.mod.o
LD [M] /home/**/test.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/**/'
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question a bit to make it more readable? Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I got the answer ....after little bit digging into the kernel code.The functions required by for_each_online_pgdat() is not exported by the kernel.I copied those functions from kernel code and attached to my code and it is working now.Thanks